# Getting current geocodes and address when current location changes by a kind of background process in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, android-asynctask

I am developing an `android app` which is working according to user current location. My requirement here is to get user current geo location as `latitude`,`longitude` with address, and some of my activity is using these values. I need to get `longitude`,`latitude` and address with a `background process`. for example this process should find these values any time user location is changed and should update these values to shared pref file so that other activities can use it whenever they need.
I really do not know where and how I should start.

Comment: why do you need to do this in a background process? Simply setting a locationListener will already take care of this for you, granted that you update your SharedPrefs with the new Lat, Lon values

Comment: yes. actually i did it.. but then I figure out that the activity which will use lng,lat waits for locationListener to get these values. It would be better lng,lat is ready in shared pref, so whenever the activities using long,lat start, they will read them just from shared pref, not waiting for location listener response

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) to see how to register a LocationListener and receive updates when user location has changed. Good place to start